# Polynomial restriction for PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Say we have a PRG $G(l,x)$ that expands a random string $x$ to length $l$ and is pseudorandom for any $l$ polynomial in $n$ (where $n = |x|$). Is $G$ pseudorandom for any $x$ of arbitrary length? I'm slightly confused as to what the polynomial restriction means.

Comment: What exactly is $\ell$ in your notation? For that matter, what is $G$? Typically, it's a function/algorithm from $\{0,1\}^*$ to itself, but in your notation the additional input $\ell$ probably makes it different.

Comment: ℓ is the length of the output produced by pseudorandom generator G, so we are assuming G to be pseudorandom up to a polynomial of the input size, n.

Comment: Please provide the full and exact definition of PRGs that your source is using. Including that of $\ell$. In particular, is the output of $G$ really of length $\ell$? That doesn't make much sense; usually it is length $\ell(n)$?